# How to use the Facebook Ads API to get custom columns in Ads Manager?

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

I've been experimenting with the Facebook Marketing API to see what I can access in terms of the user's campaigns, ad sets and ads etc. One thing I'm curious by, through the API, is it possible to get the customised columns that the user has selected when viewing metrics for their campaigns, ad sets or ads?

[image: Advert Set Custom Columns Example]

For example, the user has selected to see only Delivery, Cost and Budget metrics for their ad sets. Can I somehow know they've picked these columns from the API alone?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The Ads manager on Facebook is just another app using the Marketing API (same goes for Power editor, Graph API explorer and others).

Settings of the Ads manager aren't part of ad account data and are private to the app.